# Radio buttons "checked" attribute not working when adding markup dynamically jQuery Mobile 1.3.2

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

I do not know if this is a bug, but if you want to generate a list of radio buttons dynamically and have one selected by default the following is not working with `changePage()`:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#radio", function(e) {

HTML = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><legend>Choose a pet:</legend><input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" /><label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label><input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" /><label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label><input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3" /><label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label><input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4" /><label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label></fieldset>';

$('span.label').append(HTML);
$('div#input-radio').trigger("create");

});
```

The value of the HTML variable is copied from the docs ([Radio Buttons Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html))

Here is the page markup:

```
<div id="radio" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
            <a href="../index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-ajax="false"></a>
            <h1 class="app-name"></h1>
            <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                <ul class="input-nav">
                    <li><a class="prev" href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" >Previous</a></li>
                    <li><a class="next" href="#" data-icon="arrow-r" >Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div id="input-radio" data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            <span class="label"></span>
            <!-- List of radio buttons options generated dynamically -->
            <!-- Option 1 -->
            <!-- Option 2 -->
            <!-- Option 3 -->


        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /text -->
```

I have a multipage template where I go from one page to the other with

```
//Go to next page
        $.mobile.changePage(next_page, {
            transition : "slide",
            reverse : false,
            changeHash : false,
            allowSamePageTransition : true
        });
```

All is working fine, the radio buttons are rendered correctly but the "checked" option is never selected...

Am I missing something? Any workaround?

Edit: the only way I got it work is adding this code on `pagebeforeshow`:

```
$('div#input-radio input:radio').each(function(i) {

    if($(this).attr('checked')){


        $(this).next().trigger('vclick');
    }

});
```

Even though I hope there is a better solution...

Comment: What isn't working exactly? the `.changePage` when clicking a radiobutton?

Comment: @Omar: the radio buttons are rendered correctly but the "checked" option is never selected...

Comment: Your code works with no issues here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DawWR/ How are you calling `$.mobile.changePage`?

Comment: It is a 'vclick' callback on the prev/next button. The jsfiddle code  is triggered 'onLoad', that is probably while it is working

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't understand the problem - I'm hungry - what so you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a radio button pre-selected. I added the `checked` attribute to the one I want selected by default but it is not working...The only way I got it work is adding this code on `pagebeforeshow`: `$('div#input-radio input:radio').each(function(i) {

  if($(this).attr('checked')){
   
   
   
   $(this).next().trigger('vclick');
  }

 });`

Comment: Use `.prop('checked')` not .attr().

Comment: `attr('checked')` is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my edit, the only way I got it work is adding this code on pagebeforeshow:

```
$('div#input-radio input:radio').each(function(i) {

    if($(this).attr('checked')){

        $(this).next().trigger('vclick');
    }

});
```

maybe someone will find this useful